# Extract the sub string from end offline to a special character in batch file

Tags: batch-file, unix

HI i am trying to get the sub string **ZoomIn10X**,**ZoomIn20X**,**ZoomIn30X** etc, from a file which contain following lines below and out put that to another file

```
Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn10X

Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn20X

Job Name : STANALONE/JobId/Date/ZoomIn30X

Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn40X

Job Name : STANALONE/1234/Date/ZoomIn10X
```

i Have tried

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (

   echo %%A r "/" "\n" %%A | tail -1 >> output.txt

)
```

but its not working as properly.Can you please help

Comment: first issue - are you running on windows cmd or unix?

Answer (score 1):

on unix, with perl

```
perl -pe 's@.*/@@' input.txt
```

see `perl -h` for options and `perlop regex` for more details.
habitually substitute expressions are written with a `/` forward slash delimiter but any other character can be used as in sed. here using `@` to avoid escaping `/`.

or with shell language bash (slower because of bash read)

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "${line##*/}"
done <input.txt
```

see bash variable expansion. here `##` to remove the longest prefix.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
>output.txt (for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do echo %%~nxa)
```

Given the input lines, and handling them as paths+files references (yes, they are not, but can be handled as if they were), using the `for` replaceable parameter modifiers (see `for /?`) we request the name and extension of the file being referenced. All the output of the `for` execution is redirected to `output.txt`.

```
[W:\44365640]:# type go.cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    >output.txt (for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do echo %%~nxa)


[W:\44365640]:# type input.txt
Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn10X

Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn20X

Job Name : STANALONE/JobId/Date/ZoomIn30X

Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn40X

Job Name : STANALONE/1234/Date/ZoomIn10X

[W:\44365640]:# go
[W:\44365640]:# type output.txt
ZoomIn10X
ZoomIn20X
ZoomIn30X
ZoomIn40X
ZoomIn10X

[W:\44365640]:#
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you could define `/` as field separator and output the last field:

```
$ awk -F/ '{print $NF}' input.txt
ZoomIn10X

ZoomIn20X

ZoomIn30X

ZoomIn40X

ZoomIn10X
```

Solution outputs the last field of every line, including the empty lines you had between the data lines. If you need to filter the output somehow, please update the requirements to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think the others answers are not using batch only syntax.

The following solution should work if you have the input.txt file as you have written (I have added even option to use the solution as variable):

**EDIT:**
Added comments for the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM your input.txt file looks like this
REM Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn10X
REM Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn20X
REM Job Name : STANALONE/JobId/Date/ZoomIn30X
REM Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn40X
REM Job Name : STANALONE/1234/Date/ZoomIn10X

REM if you wished to use variable
REM SET final_name=""

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A IN (input.txt) DO (
    SET temp_var=%%A
    FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=/" %%B IN ("!temp_var!") DO (
        SET temp_var_B=%%B
        IF "!temp_var_B!" EQU "Date" (
            FOR /F "tokens=5 delims=^/" %%C IN ("!temp_var!") DO (
                ECHO %%C >> output.txt
                REM if you wished to use variable
                REM SET final_name=!final_name!,%%C
            )
        ) ELSE (
           ECHO %%B >> output.txt
           REM if you wished to use variable
           REM SET final_name=!final_name!,%%B
        )
    )
)
ECHO All collected variables: !final_name!
ENDLOCAL
```

This is somewhat inefficient solution, much better you can find below, but collects also variables.  It uses the fact that you can split string multiple times and if you have different string length you can still extract it based on the string, if it is the same, like in your case a "Date".  First FOR splits the string based on ":" character and the other FORs based on "/" char.  There are two FORs as you have different length of the extracted string.

**EDIT :**
I think I was too quick to find a solution.  When I thought about it I recognized it as very "crude" solution.  I'll also comment it better as I have posted only the code.

The more efficient solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM your input.txt file looks like this
REM Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn10X
REM Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn20X
REM Job Name : STANALONE/JobId/Date/ZoomIn30X
REM Job Name : STANALONE/1234/JobId/Date/ZoomIn40X
REM Job Name : STANALONE/1234/Date/ZoomIn10X

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A IN (input.txt) DO (
   SET var=%%A
   IF EXIST input.txt (
       ECHO !var:~-9! >> output.txt
   ) ELSE (
       ECHO !var:~-9! > output.txt
   )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Description:
First comes the **FOR /F** with **"tokens=2"** (takes a second part) and **"delims=:"** uses a ":" as delimiter.

**The core** of the solution uses the fact that you have at the end constant size string (9 characters to be exact) which you want to extract - **!var:~-9!**. Uses expanded variable and takes 9 characters from the end of the string which was selected with the FOR statement.

The solution needs to have the **SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION** there as it uses the expansion.

There is also a **IF EXISTS** clause so it will create a new file every time you run it.  That is not a vital part of the script and you may comment it out.